# Summation formula needed

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help with creating a formula in Google Sheets for the sum of:

```
x*(0.95^1+0.95^2+0.95^3+...+0.95^n)
```

where x is a constant, and n is a positive integer. The formula must fit in one cell.

Comment: Reduce the series into its single operation formula and use that :)

Comment: Hint..it looks the computation of compound interest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
=x*SERIESSUM(.95,1,1,{1,1,1,1,1})
```

While there very possibly a ready-made statistical or financial worksheet function for this, you seem to be happy with the results from this formula offered in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53970289/summation-formula-needed/53970443#53970443).

You just need to generate the array *n* times with *n* being the value from a cell on the worksheet.

`INDEX(ROW(1:4), , )` returns a result of `{1, 2, 3, 4}` as a true array.

To convert `{1, 2, 3, 4}` to `{1, 1, 1, 1}` use a SIGN function 'wrapper' around the row numbers.

```
=INDEX(SIGN(ROW(1:4)), , )              'returns {1, 1, 1, 1} as a true array
```

To vary the length of the array, use INDIRECT to build the ROW reference. With 4 in  C10, this returns the same result.

```
=INDEX(SIGN(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C10))),,) 'returns {1, 1, 1, 1} as a true array
'proof
=SUM(INDEX(SIGN(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C10))),,)) 'returns 4
```

Put that together with the rest of the formula as a standard formula with INDEX in array mode.

```
=B10*SERIESSUM(0.95, 1, 1, INDEX(SIGN(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C10))),,))
```

If you don't wish to use INDEX in its array mode, you can dispense with it and add an ARRAYFORMULA wrapper instead.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLzZB.png)

Comment: This is a next-level formula. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
=x*SERIESSUM(.95,1,1,{1,1,1,1,1})
```

where the array has *n* `1`s (5 for example).

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. Is there a way to create an array with n amount of 1s without having to type them in the formula? In that case this solves my problem. In my particular case, I need to get the value n from a cell for it to work properly.

Comment: yep, you can create an array with n amount of any number like so: SEQUENCE(1, num_elements, value, 0) 

so, to get a sequence of {1,1,1} you'd do SEQUENCE(1,3,1,0)